# Cannot connect to Postgres database , there is authentication issue

Tags: spring, postgresql

When trying to log onto the form then I get error in Tomcat :

> Authentication type 10 is not supported. Verify that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet and that it uses a driver-supported authentication scheme.

How to fix it ?

Comment: You need to update your JDBC driver

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this is how I set the driver : `jdbc.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wktools` ; so how can I change it ?

Comment: You need to download a newer version of the .jar file from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/ or see the linked duplicate it includes a description how to do it with Maven

Comment: ok, it works : I modified the pom.xml